# Cannot use newly installed plugins (node modules) in Nuxt pages/components

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

First off, I'm a beginner with NuxtJS and front-end development in general, so it might be that I'm missing something - though I do believe I went through all the options before posting here. Apologies in advance if that is not the case.

I've been having trouble using installed modules that I've registered as plugins. For example, take [`mapbox-sdk`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js).

After installing it with `npm install @mapbox/mapbox-sdk`, which correctly creates `@mapbox/mapbox-sdk` in `node_modules`, I register it in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
  plugins: [
    ...
    "~/plugins/mapbox-sdk.js",
  ],
```

Of course, I also create the `mapbox-sdk.js` file in `plugins/`, containing:

```
import "@mapbox/mapbox-sdk";
```

Then, in a page (say, `myMap.vue`), when I try:

```
var mapboxClient = mapboxSdk({ accessToken: MY_ACCESS_TOKEN });
```

which is the basic usage example in the documentation, I get:

```
mapboxSdk is not defined
```

in the console. This behavior extends to every single module I installed today, but is not the case for modules I had previously installed.

Comment: Try killing the server and running `npm run dev` again. I think you're also supposed to either say `Vue.use(pluginVarName)` or export the variable your're trying to call

Comment: @S.Ramjit Yeah, that was my first thought, I've done it a couple of times by now. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to help. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js/issues/379 the last comment may be of some use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're getting the error `mapboxSdk is not defined` is because there are a few issues with the way you've set up this plugin.

Docs here https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins/, they have some useful diagrams.

There are a couple of ways you can use this package.

### Plugin

```js
// ~/plugins/mapbox-sdk.js
import mapboxSdk from '@mapbox/mapbox-sdk'

export default (_ctx, inject) => {
  // Exposing the mapboxSdk to your Nuxt app as $mapBox.
  inject('mapBox', mapboxSdk)
}
```

Then in `nuxt.config.js`, same as you've already done.

```js
plugins: [
  ...
  "~/plugins/mapbox-sdk.js",
],
```

Then in your component `myMap.vue`

```js
var mapboxClient = this.$mapBox({ accessToken: MY_ACCESS_TOKEN });
```

---

### Directly in the component:

If you don't wish to use a plugin, the way that @kissu mentioned above https://stackoverflow.com/a/67421094/12205549 will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this after the import to let Vue know that this method exists (in the same `.vue` file) at first

```html
<script>
import mapboxSdk from '@mapbox/mapbox-sdk'
export default {
  methods: {
    mapboxSdk,
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('mapbox function >>', mapboxSdk)
  },
}
</script>
```

Do you have it working in a `.vue` component at first ?

[image]

Comment: Explicitly importing it in the page's <script> seems to have worked. An odd issue, considering other modules I've been using don't require this. Thank you very much!

Comment: It depends on the type of module and how it works but this one is nice because you only import it into the `.vue` component rather than globally.